# Unix Awk Command

Tags: unix, awk

Awk, I am new this this command, I know it can list out the text file with condition, but i have no idea how to list them when there is a "," in between the text, how do you count the "," in as $1.

but if its email, email won't show for some reason, I am thinking maybe I should include the "," ?, i am not sure how to solve the problem, and don't know what the problem is.
for example i want to show customerid and customersname, i will use:

```
awk'{print $1,$2}' 


Customerid, customersname, email
12312322, MIKE, example@gmail.com
51231221, CALVIN, example2@gmail.com 
91234232, LISA, example3@gmail.com
12359432, DICK, example4@gmail.com
94123432, ORAN, example5@gmail.com
63242333, KEVIN, example6@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the comma as separator? Use `-F` like that:

```
awk -F, '{print $1,$2}'
```

If you want comma *and* spaces as separator you can use a regex:

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]*' '{print $1,$2}'
```

Comment: HI, Thank you for the help, This works, but i am not sure of this part,-F',[[:space:]]*' What does it mean, can you please explain to me?

Comment: @user3488212 Use a separator like `,` or `, ` or `,  `.  So it removes the unneeded blank spaces.  It does mean `,` and 0 or more spaces after it. (read about regex)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I got your question properly. You can specifiy the input field separator using the `-F` command line option:

```
awk -F, '{print $1, $2}' your.csv
```

Output:

```
Customerid  customersname
12312322  MIKE
51231221  CALVIN
91234232  LISA
12359432  DICK
94123432  ORAN
63242333  KEVIN
```

Answer (score 1):

simply using `FS`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," } {print $1,$2}'
```

from `man awk`:

> **7. Builtin-variables**
>
> ```
>    The following variables are built-in and initialized before program execution.    
>          ...
>           FS        splits records into fields as a regular expression.
>          ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code needed**

```
awk -F "," '{print $1,$2}' input.txt
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Customerid, customersname
> 12312322, MIKE
> 51231221, CALVIN
> 91234232, LISA
> 12359432, DICK
> 94123432, ORAN
> 63242333, KEVIN
> ```

**Explanation:**

> -F = Field separator
>
> "," = using comma because columns are separated by ,
>
> '{print $1,$2}' = display first and second column
>
> input.txt = the file you want to pass

Hope its help.